# Qt. QDateTime unpredictable behaviour with timezones and addSecs

Tags: c++, qt, qdatetime

I can't realize what's wrong.

```
QTimeZone zone1(QTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
QTimeZone zone2(QTimeZone("Asia/Yekaterinburg"));
QDateTime test = QDateTime(QDate(2016, 11, 11), QTime(15,00), zone1);
qDebug() << test;//QDateTime(2016-11-11 15:00:00.000 MSK Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Europe/Moscow)
test = test.addSecs(5*60);
qDebug() << test;//QDateTime(2016-11-11 15:05:00.000 MSK Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Europe/Moscow)
```

This is working fine with Europe/Moscow(+3), but when I change timezone to Asia/Yekaterinburg(+5) it works very strange

```
QTimeZone zone2(QTimeZone("Asia/Yekaterinburg"));
QDateTime test = QDateTime(QDate(2016, 11, 11), QTime(15,00), zone2);
qDebug() << test;//QDateTime(2016-11-11 15:00:00.000  Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Asia/Yekaterinburg)
test = test.addSecs(5*60);
qDebug() << test;//QDateTime(2016-11-11 10:05:00.000  Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Asia/Yekaterinburg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange thing, I reproduced it using Qt 5.6.0 with this adjusted example.

```
QDateTime test1 = QDateTime(QDate(2016, 11, 11), QTime(15, 00), QTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
QDateTime test2 = QDateTime(QDate(2016, 11, 11), QTime(15, 00), QTimeZone("Asia/Yekaterinburg"));
QDateTime test3 = QDateTime(QDate(2016, 11, 11), QTime(15, 00), QTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
qDebug() << test1;
qDebug() << test2;
qDebug() << test3;
qDebug() << test1.addSecs(5*60);
qDebug() << test2.addSecs(5*60);
qDebug() << test3.addSecs(5*60);
```

Output:

```
QDateTime(2016-11-11 15:00:00.000 RTZ 2 Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Europe/Moscow)
QDateTime(2016-11-11 15:00:00.000 RTZ 4 Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Asia/Yekaterinburg)
QDateTime(2016-11-11 15:00:00.000 MEZ   Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Europe/Berlin)
QDateTime(2016-11-11 18:05:00.000 RTZ 2 Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Europe/Moscow)
QDateTime(2016-11-11 20:05:00.000 RTZ 4 Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Asia/Yekaterinburg)
QDateTime(2016-11-11 15:05:00.000 MEZ   Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Europe/Berlin)
QDateTime(2016-11-11 18:05:00.000 RTZ 2 Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Europe/Moscow)
```

Note that I added another time zone, which is my local time zone. You probably note that this is the time zone which works (`Europe/Berlin`).

Next thing to do is offset analysis. You see the following offsets:

- `Europe/Moscow`: +3h
- `Asia/Yekaterinburg`: +5h

Looking at some [time zone map](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Standard_World_Time_Zones.png) one might note that the offset between the two zones is exactly *2h*. So where is the *+3h* coming from?

Needless to say, I ran another test.

```
QDateTime dt = QDateTime(QDate(2016, 11, 11), QTime(15, 00), QTimeZone("UTC"));
qDebug() << dt;
qDebug() << dt.addSecs(5*60);
qDebug() << dt.addSecs(5*60).toTimeZone(QTimeZone("Asia/Yekaterinburg"));
```

Output:

```
QDateTime(2016-11-11 15:00:00.000 UTC   Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) UTC)
QDateTime(2016-11-11 15:05:00.000 UTC   Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) UTC)
QDateTime(2016-11-11 20:05:00.000 RTZ 4 Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Asia/Yekaterinburg)
```

And here we go: It seems like Qt is not transfering the time zone to UTC before calculation but uses it as UTC which results in a back shift with the corresponding offset.

But wait...

```
QDateTime dt = QDateTime(QDate(2016, 11, 11), QTime(15, 00), Qt::UTC);
qDebug() << dt.toLocalTime();
qDebug() << dt.toTimeZone(QTimeZone("Asia/Yekaterinburg"));
qDebug() << dt.toUTC();
```

Output:

```
QDateTime(2016-11-11 16:00:00.000 MEZ   Qt::TimeSpec(LocalTime))
QDateTime(2016-11-11 20:00:00.000 RTZ 4 Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Asia/Yekaterinburg)
QDateTime(2016-11-11 15:00:00.000 UTC   Qt::TimeSpec(UTC))
```

Now it looks like if the constructor gets a time zone it assumes it is UTC, not the provided one. If leaving it out Qt takes local time, which is obvious.

As it is not documented where it [used](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimezone.html) to [be](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html) this seems like a bug to me.

---

Long story short, what to do?

If applicable, try to provide times as local time or UTC, tranform them to UTC, calcualte with them and then format to desired output.

```
QDateTime dt = QDateTime(QDate(2016, 11, 11), QTime(10, 00), Qt::UTC);
qDebug() << dt.toTimeZone(QTimeZone("Asia/Yekaterinburg"));
qDebug() << dt.addSecs(5*60).toTimeZone(QTimeZone("Asia/Yekaterinburg"));
```

Output:

```
QDateTime(2016-11-11 15:00:00.000 RTZ 4 Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Asia/Yekaterinburg)
QDateTime(2016-11-11 15:05:00.000 RTZ 4 Qt::TimeSpec(TimeZone) Asia/Yekaterinburg)
```

Comment: I needed to manipulate with time zones just for scheduling. For example my car departures Yekaterinburg and local time is 15:00, so when I arrive to Moscow it's next day 18:00 by local time of Yekaterinburg, and I want to just change timezone and it will lead to changing time to Moscow local. 
So I understood that the behaviour of QDateTime is very weird, and for my task it's not necessary to setTimezone, I can just apply shifts between old timezone and new one. the only problem is to remembering last timezone

Comment: But It doesn't work too... :D
    `QTimeZone zoneNew(QTimeZone("Europe/Moscow")); 
    QTimeZone zoneOld(QTimeZone("Asia/Yekaterinburg"));
    QDateTime test = QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc();
    test.setTime(QTime(18, 00));
    qDebug() << zoneOld.offsetFromUtc(test); // 0
    qDebug() << zoneNew.offsetFromUtc(test); // 10800`
Very Weird

Comment: @AtnesNess See my last example which worked for me. It puzzles me also what Qt is doing there.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible workaround is to use this [free, open source, C++11/14 library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) which builds on `<chrono>`:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto zone1 = make_zoned("Europe/Moscow", local_days{2016_y/11/11} + 15h);
    std::cout << zone1 << '\n';
    zone1 = zone1.get_local_time() + 5min;
    std::cout << zone1 << '\n';

    auto zone2 = make_zoned("Asia/Yekaterinburg", local_days{2016_y/11/11} + 15h);
    std::cout << zone2 << '\n';
    zone2 = zone2.get_local_time() + 5min;
    std::cout << zone2 << '\n';
}
```

The output is:

```
2016-11-11 15:00:00 MSK
2016-11-11 15:05:00 MSK
2016-11-11 15:00:00 +05
2016-11-11 15:05:00 +05
```

Here are conversion functions to/from `QDate`:

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#QDate